# Toggle CheckBox inside a ViewCell in Xmarin.Forms

Tags: checkbox, xamarin.forms, toggle, code-behind

I would like to know how to toggle the current checkbox inside my ListView - ViewCell on item tapped event.

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewCities"
                      ItemSelected="ListViewCities_ItemSelected"
                      ItemTapped="ListViewCities_ItemTapped">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox x:Name="chkSelectedCity" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                       FontSize="Medium"
                                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Here is my item tapped event.

```
private void ListViewCities_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    //Here i want to toggle the current check box as true
    //something like chkSelectedCity.checked = true;
}
```

Comment: you need to bind the checkbox to a property on your model, and then toggle that property on tapped

Comment: actually i am a beginner in xamarin forms. it would be much helpful if you post an example or a link to an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm#interactive-mvvm) to bind a ViewModel for ListView , when data of model changed , **UI** will update along with that .

Such as creating a **CellClass** as follow :

```
public class CellClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { set; get; }

    private bool selected { get; set; }

    public bool Selected
    {
        set
        {
            if (selected != value)
            {
                selected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return selected;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then setting some data for `CellClass` in a new created class (ListViewModel) :

```
public class ListViewModel
{
    public List<CellClass> cellItems { set; get; }

    public ListViewModel()
    {
        cellItems = new List<CellClass>();
        cellItems.Add(new CellClass() { Name = "One", Selected = false });
        cellItems.Add(new CellClass() { Name = "Two", Selected = false });
        cellItems.Add(new CellClass() { Name = "Three", Selected = false });
        cellItems.Add(new CellClass() { Name = "Four", Selected = false });
        cellItems.Add(new CellClass() { Name = "Five", Selected = false });
        cellItems.Add(new CellClass() { Name = "Six", Selected = false });

    }
}
```

Now **Xaml** code will as follow :

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewCities"
            ItemSelected="listViewCities_ItemSelected"
            ItemTapped="ListViewCities_ItemTapped">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox x:Name="chkSelectedCity"
                                IsChecked="{Binding Selected}"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                            FontSize="Medium"
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In **ContentPage** can deal with the `ListViewCities_ItemTapped` method and binding model for `ListView` :

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ListViewModel listViewModel = new ListViewModel();
    listViewCities.ItemsSource = listViewModel.cellItems;
}

private void ListViewCities_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    //Here i want to toggle the current check box as true
    //something like chkSelectedCity.checked = true;
    var model = e.Item as CellClass;
    if (model.Selected)
    {
        model.Selected = false;
    }
    else
    {
        model.Selected = true;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("clicked");
}
```

The **effect** :

[image]

This is the [sample project link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/50wnotqy70dj68w/AppListViewCheck.rar?dl=0) for reference , you can have a look when have time .

Comment: I did not find time till now to try your solution. I'll try to check tomorrow and let you know. Thanks for posting.

Comment: @Thameem Okey , no matter what results , feel free to update here :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it worked like a charm. But im wondering how to handle this for many properties lets say 10 props in a class.. Looks tedious..

Comment: @Thameem What do you mean *10 props in a class* , you can detail that .

Comment: Jiang - How about i have a checkbox button and another checkbox and a switch as a third one. should i follow this mentioned method of backing field concept for every property i add into my model and i want them to update as soon as i toggle them in xaml.. I hope you get my doubt.. if not pls ping me back. i'll explain further..

Comment: @Thameem Yeah , each propery need to add model . That depends on the needed scene . If later meet this needs , you can have a try with that .

Comment: Jiang Usually, I upvote questions which may be helpful to the newbies... :)

Answer (score 1):

add a bool property to your model

```
public bool Selected { get; set; }
```

then bind your checkbox to it

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Selected}" />
```

then in your handler

```
private void ListViewCities_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (MyClass)e.Item;
    item.Selected = !item.Selected;
}
```

Comment: It is not working. should i use ObsevableCollection<> ?

Comment: Does your model implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Well, it needs to